# How do I design a program that does completely different tasks concurrently?

Tags: java

I've just got my feet wet with multi-threading and it's really awesome.  I find myself trying to figure out new ways I can use it make things better and I think I found one but I'm unsure how to design the program for this.

I have a queue server that multiple clients consume and produce data to but to kick start the process I run a Java program on to put some initial data for them to start. then my program is done and I have excess capacity on the queue server but nothing is really running on it.  So I want to try to do some maintenance tasks, run a service, and do low priority stuff.I'm not sure how do that though.  How do I design a program that does completely different tasks concurrently?

Typically I just wrap my programs in a `while (true)` loop and it does a single task and I realize I cannot do two while loops at the same time in the same process (maybe nested?).  To show a simplified example, I put a bunch of code that runs a runnable (maybe it'll process a low priority queue) and a service that monitors a socket and replies back (I might want to add more depending on CPU usage).  How do I get them all to work together? Is there a better way to design it (I know long term its probably better to run multiple Java processes but right now I am just trying to manage a single file and I suspect there's a way to give the socket service a higher priority than processing the queue within the file but if they are both running in different files I don't know how to lower one over the other instead of them fighting for resources)?

In a nutshell, I want it to provide a service to other systems (server socket, in the example) and when its idle I want it to do a few other tasks.

Example (if you understand what I'm asking this code may not be necessary to read):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class multipleThreads {

    private ServerSocket server;
    private int port = 7777;

    public void ServerSocketExample() {
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("starting");
        
        ServerSocketExample example = new ServerSocketExample();
        example.handleConnection();
        
        while (true) {
            //monitor low low priority queue
        }       
    }
    public void handleConnection() {
        System.out.println("Waiting for client message...");

        //
        // The server do a loop here to accept all connection initiated by the
        // client application.
        //
        while (true) {
            try {
                Socket socket = server.accept();
                new ConnectionHandler(socket);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable {
    private Socket socket;

    public ConnectionHandler(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;

        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        try
        {
            //
            // Read a message sent by client application
            //
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            String message = (String) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("Message Received: " + message);

            //
            // Send a response information to the client application
            //
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            oos.writeObject("Hi...");

            ois.close();
            oos.close();
            socket.close();

            System.out.println("Waiting for client message...");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class MonitorQueue implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //do work when stuff comes in the queue
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/); e.g. [Search?](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=java%20run%20task%20concurrent&oq=java%20run%20tasks%20concu&aq=0A&aqi=q-A1&aql=1&gs_l=hp.11.0.33i29.407l5238l0l6805l22l21l1l0l0l0l133l1777l18j3l22l0.eqn%2Cfixedpos%3Dfalse%2Cboost_normal%3D20%2Cboost_high%3D1000%2Ccconf%3D0-95%2Cmin_length%3D2.1.&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=ff7aa66f60e2d50e&biw=1280&bih=687&pf=p&pdl=300)

Comment: [Thread.setPriority(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setPriority%28int%29)?

Comment: @nobeh I've tried to code it but having two while loops don't work, and I wash't sure how to  adjust priority of tasks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly recommend you take a look at this project: Java Concurrent Animated. I found this probably the best way to get my head around concurrency concepts in Java: it's animated, interactive, and you can just take one concept at a time and get a good understanding.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaconcurrenta/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package. It's full off goodies for doing exactly the kinds of things you describe.

In particular, check out the [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) factory class which lets you build `Thread Pools` that allow multiple tasks to be scheduled and run concurrently on any number of `Threads` you specify.

Oracle has some great tutorials on using `Executors`:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html

Comment: ahh..so I can have one thread monitoring different things(in a while loop for example) then based on the item send it to Executors to launch different tasks? can I set number of threads or priority for tasks? like a heavy task may get more threads and higher priority over a lower one?

Comment: When you add a `Runnable` to an [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) `Runnable.run()` will be executed on a single `Thread` managed by the `Executor` (which might have many such `Threads` executing many different `Runnables`). If you want your task to be automatically split up among multiple threads, that's a whole different ball of wax and a question in-and-of itself (there are `c` libraries like [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/) which handle automatic parallelization of loops, but I'm not familiar with anything like that for Java)

Comment: As far as controlling `thread priority`, look at the [ThreadPoolExecutor constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#ThreadPoolExecutor(int, int, long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit, java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue, java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory)) which take a [ThreadFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html) as an argument. You could create two `ThreadPoolExecutors` with different `ThreadFactories` which create threads with different priorities.

Comment: Then simply add your high priority tasks to the one executor, your low priority ones to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Concurrency is hard, you can read Java Concurrency in Practice, but even the experts have difficulties.
Look for a training course in your area.
I would like to recommend [Concurrency Specialist Courses](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/courses/concurrency.jsp) which is based on Java Concurrency in Practice and endorsed by the author, Brian Goetz